# Which algorithm should I use to calculate the given math sequence?

Tags: c++, math

The user must enter a number *n* (1; infinity). Then the program does this:

cos1/sin1 * (cos1+cos2)/(sin1+sin2) * … * (cos1+cos2+...+cos⁡ n)/(sin1+sin2+...+sin ⁡n )

I tried to calculate that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int n;
double res;

cout << "Enter n: ";
cin >> n;

for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
{
    res = cos(i) / sin(i);
}
cout << res;
}
```

But I don't know which algorithm would do it correctly.

Comment: `n` may be infinity? That will take a while to calculate....

Comment: Hint: You can store the partial sums for the numerator and denominator.

Comment: Also: [read this](https://en.wikibooks.org/w/index.php?title=Trigonometry/The_summation_of_finite_series)

Answer (score 2):

Since you need to divide the two sums in each step, you need to store those sums, and multiply an accumulating product with the result of dividing them.

```
int main()
{
    int n;
    cout << "Enter n: ";
    cin >> n;
    
    double cos_sum = 0.0;
    double sin_sum = 0.0;
    double res = 1.0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        cos_sum += cos(i);
        sin_sum += sin(i);
        res *= cos_sum / sin_sum;
    }
    cout << res;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are basically three quantities that accumulate during the iteration. They are:

```
C[N] = cos1+cos2+cos3+cos3+ .... cosN
S[N] = sin1+sin2+sin3+sin3+ .... sinN
X[N] = C[1] / S[1] * C[2] / S[2] * ... C[N] / S[N]
```

The recursive relations are:

```
C[0] = 0
C[N + 1] = C[N] + cosN+1  
S[0] = 0
S[N + 1] = S[N] + sinN+1

X[0] = 1
X[N + 1] = X[N] * C[N+1] / S[N+1]
```

Using this it should be straightforward to write the loop:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int n;
    double X = 1;
    double C = 0;
    double S = 0;

    cout << "Enter n: ";
    cin >> n;

    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        C += cos(i);
        S += sin(i);
        X *= C / S;
    }
    cout << X;
}
```